# How to remove non existent modules prior to injecting them in main module?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, circular-reference, angularjs-module

I am using AngularJS v1.2.16

I have 3 angular projects, one application and 2 components, all 3 are configured independly via requirejs. Now, let me talk about the main js file of each of these 3 projects.

app.js - my main application file

```
var registeredDependencies = ['myapp.ctrls','myapp.services','myapp.commons','comp1.main','comp2.main'];

var buildValidDependencies = function() {
    var validDependencies = angular.copy(registeredDependencies);
    _.each(validDependencies, function(dep) {
        try {
            setTimeout(function() {
                angular.module(dep);
            });
        } catch (e) {
            var index = validDependencies.indexOf(dep);
            validDependencies.splice(index, 1);
            console.log("'" + dep + "' removed as it failed the existence test.");
        }
    });
    return validDependencies;
};

angular.module('myapp.main', buildValidDependencies());
```

comp1.js - widget 1 to be used by app.js

```
angular.module('comp1.main', []);
```

comp2.js - widget 2 to be used by app.js

```
angular.module('comp2.main', []);
```

Both comp1 and comp2 use 'myapp.commons' however they are not explicitly injected in comp1.main and comp2.main modules, as my application's main module 'myapp.main' injects all 3 modules 'myapp.commons','comp1.main','comp2.main', so commons is available to comp1 and comp2 implicitely. I don't want to inject commons in comp1 and comp2 to avoid requirejs configuration for them at 3 different places.

Now the real problem is ...
comp1 and comp2 are optional components. If any of doesn't exist at runtime, my application should still be running. For this very purpose, my buildValidDependencies() function verifies existence of the modules prior to inject them in my application's main module. I expect angular.module(dependency), would just suffice to verify this. It works fine in my local machine, but fails in production, where comp1.js and comp2.js are downloaded from CDN. I observed there was some timing issue, and hence I wrapped this code inside setTimeout() function. This appeared to have done the trick till today. However I see today angular.module(dep) never fails even if the corresponding module doesn't exist and I found this is because of setTimeout().

I am unable to find this sudden change, and hence wondering if this approach is really appropriate or not. Could you advise what is wrong or else suggest reliable way of removing non existent modules prior to injecting them in main module?